# How can i edit pixels of an image to change its values?

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I am new to OpenCv and NDK, and i can not find any good help anywhere to modify pixels of an image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming in Java:

If you have an image as an object of Mat. You could use m.get() to read and m.put() to write back values using double[].

Documentation of Mat: http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html

Otherwise in C++ and NDK:
Mat.At is the simplestsolution, a possible use is

> Mat.At(1,1) = 255;

Or

> Mat.At(0,0) = 1.0

But be aware of type you had instantiate your matrix.